# Magento - Shopping carrt rules not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-rules

When trying to set up a rule in Magento to accomplish this:

X% off specific products when you order Y or more

Its not working. I have followed this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes and its STILL not working.

Here are screen shots showing you i'm not crazy and followed their rules EXACTLY...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was right this can't be done with configurable products. For whatever reason it doesn't detect the child sku's.

This has been confirmed by the Magento Enterprise Team. If there is a change i will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is set up to only allow a discount if there are 3 or more of the products shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBZCa.png, not any set of 3 products